# Permanently disabled touchpad with function key

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchpad

I pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on my Samsung 9 laptop, which disables the touchpad. It worked, but now I can't re-enable it. Clicking (and even click-through tapping) work, but the pointer doesn't move. If I `cat /dev/input/mice`, it shows output when I use the touchpad. Restarting the laptop doesn't help, and the touchpad is listed as enabled in the various graphical utilities I tried, including `xinput`. What else can I try? I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

I tried swapping my external mouse (`/dev/input/mouse0`) and my touchpad (`/dev/input/mouse1`) by renaming their `/dev` entries, and then rebooting fixed it somehow. I was thinking that renaming devices forced linux to "rescan" (recreate) the `/dev` files, but then I thought that the `/dev` filesystem is mounted every reboot and recreated by the kernel, so I don't really understand why that worked.

Comment: fwiw, nothing actually listens to the /dev/input/mouse* event nodes. everything uses /dev/input/event* now